# UIPageViewController with title and custom indicator

Tags: ios, swift

I have started learning swift 3 in the previous week, and I'm trying out a few stuff. In android, I can create the below layout with a tab layout and a view pager and customaise the tab layout indicator. However, I'm still a bit lost between the UIKIT. I have already figured the UIPageViewController for swiping, but how about having a title and customise the indicator? Whats the name of that view so I can learn about it
[image]

Comment: How is `android` related to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

glad to hear you have decided give Swift and iOS a try!

To start with, you should check out [`UISegmentedControl`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol) which enables you to have a control for switching between "Favoriten" and "Alle spiele" views. A quick Google search found a few custom implementation of `UISegmentedControl` some looking very much like [what you want](https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl).

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know about be using UIPageViewController or UIScrollView with paging. well if i go with the library you mentioned, how do I go with custom indicator as in the picture for instance?

Comment: You can use [`set​Image(_:​for​Segment​At:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol/1618582-setimage) to set an image as indicator of your segment index.

Comment: That would set an icon for each segment/title, I meant I want to have a triangle indicator below the title text

Comment: There is no built in triangle indicator. You could then have 2 images for each of your segments - first representing selected state (triangle) and second representing deselected state (without triangle)

Comment: Yes, I know that. I'm trying now to figure what's the best way to implement a custom indicator for selected and deselected state